# Make .tar or .gz file in window using perl

Tags: perl, window, tar, gzip

I will try to make .tar or .gz file. But I have some issues like:

1. It takes the complete path

   ```
   D:\test\jtax-issue11-16\title.xml
   D:\test\jtax-issue11-16\artwork
   D:\test\jtax-issue11-16\artwork\cover.png
   ```

Note: the above is also my folder structure.

But my requirement is:

```
jtax-issue11-16\title.xml
jtax-issue11-16\artwork
jtax-issue11-16\artwork\cover.png
```

Which means create .tar or .gz file with the current folder name only

My code is :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename 'basename';
use Cwd;

my $current_path = getcwd;
my @inventory = ();
find (sub { push @inventory, $File::Find::name }, $current_path);
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();  
$tar->add_files(@inventory);
$tar->write('a.tar');
```

If I use basename, then it produces an error. I don't understand how to use basename or how to create .tar or .gz file with the current folder name.

Comment: You could fetch the current folder & file name `jtax-issue11-16\title.xml` from `D:\test\jtax-issue11-16\title.xml`using `regex`.

Answer (score 1):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my $base_dir = '.';

my @files =
   map { s{^\Q$base_dir/}{}r }
   File::Find::Rule
   ->mindepth(1)
   ->in($base_dir);
```

or

```
use File::Find qw( find );

my $base_dir = '.';

my @files;
find(
   {
      wanted => sub { push @files, s{^\Q$base_dir/}{}r },
      no_chdir => 1,
   },
   $base_dir
);
shift(@files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are in `$current_path` when you call `find()`, you should just pass `.` to `find()`. That way all of the paths you get in `$File::Find::name` will be relative to the current directory;

```
my $current_path = getcwd;
my @inventory = ();
find (sub { push @inventory, $File::Find::name }, '.');
```

That will give you paths like:

```
.\jtax-issue11-16\title.xml
.\jtax-issue11-16\artwork
.\jtax-issue11-16\artwork\cover.png
```

But you could use `s/^\.\\//` to remove the `.\` from the beginning of that path if it's important to you. The easiest place to do that might be after you have built `@inventory`.

```
@inventory = map { s/^\.\\//; $_ } @inventory;
```

Comment: Sorry to say, But it create two folder insde the .tar file one is "." and another is "jtax-issue11-16".

Answer (score 0):

I will add **Dave Cross** code in my file and get my o/p.
Code is below:-

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename 'basename';
use 5.010;
use Cwd;

my $current_dir = getcwd;
my @tar_files;
my @inventory = ();
find (sub { push @inventory, $File::Find::name }, $current_dir);
my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();
@inventory = map { s/^$current_dir\///; $_ } @inventory;
foreach my $temp (@inventory)
    {
        # skip my file name which is conv.pl 
        #  and skip blank entry in tar, which is created by $current_dir
        if ($temp =~ m/conv\.pl/ || $temp =~ m/conv\.exe/ ||$temp =~/$current_dir/)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            push (@tar_files , $temp );
        }
    }
$tar->add_files(@tar_files);
$tar->write($file_name.".tar");
```